# Expressing a chain of boolean ORs using ILP

Tags: optimization, modeling, integer-programming

How to express a chain of **OR** operations in an ILP in which each expression is a less than or equal constraint and the left hand side variable in all inequalities is always the same? All the variables are binary.

For example, I would like to express $x_1 \leq x_3$ OR $x_1 \leq x_4$ OR $x_1 \leq x_6$. Notice the first variable in all the inequality constraints is $x_1$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Derivation via conjunctive normal form:
\begin{equation}
x_1 \implies \underset{i=2}{\overset n{\lor}} x_i \\
\neg x_1 \bigvee \underset{i=2}{\overset n{\lor}} x_i \\
1 - x_1 + \sum_{i=2}^n x_i \ge 1 \\
x_1 \le \sum_{i=2}^n x_i
\end{equation}

Answer (score 9):

Your example constraint is equivalent to $x_1 \le \text{max}(x_3,x_4,x_6)$, which I will generalize to $x_1 \le \max(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$.

This max can be handled using section 2.6 "Logical OR" of [FICO MIP formulations and linearizations: Quick reference](https://www.fico.com/en/resource-download-file/3217).

Specifically, introduce a binary variable, $d$, to be constrained as follows so that it will be equal to $\text{max}(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$

\begin{align}d &\ge x_i, \quad i=2,\ldots, n\\d &\le \sum\limits_{i=2}^n x_i\end{align}

Now add the constraint: $x_1 \le d$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Re: your edit. Centering constraints is o.k., but I prefer my dots at "ground level" rather than in the middle of the air. I think my way is far more common.

Comment: Right, changed from `\cdots` to `\ldots`, rather than `...`

Comment: Note that if you are not interested in the variable $d$ itself, you can eliminate the variable to obtain $x_1 \le \sum_{i=2}^n x_i$ as in Rob Pratt's answer.

Comment: @Kevin Dalmeijer Yes indeedy.