# Expressing an implication as ILP where each implication term comprises a chain of boolean ORs

Tags: optimization, modeling, integer-programming, nonlinear-programming, logical-constraints

Consider an implication of the form $A \implies B$ where both $A, B$ comprises a chain of Boolean OR variables. For example, $(a_1 \lor a_2 \lor a_3) \implies  (b_1 \lor b_2 \lor b_3)$. How can this be expressed as an ILP? All variables are Boolean.

I have derived the following using CNF, however it turns out to be non-linear, can this be expressed in Linear Form?

Let us suppose $A = \{ a_1, a_2, a_3\}$ and $B = \{ b_1, b_2, b_3\}$. thus,

\begin{equation}
\bigvee A \implies \bigvee B \\
\overline{\bigvee A} \bigvee \left(\bigvee B\right) \\
\left(\bigwedge_{a \in A} \overline a\right) \bigvee  \left(\bigvee B\right) \\
\left(\bigwedge_{a \in A} (1-a)\right) \bigvee  \left(\bigvee B\right) \\
\left(\prod_{a \in A} (1-a)\right) \bigvee  \left(\sum_{b \in B} b\right) \\
\prod_{a \in A} (1-a) +  \sum_{b \in B} b \geq 1
\end{equation}

Thus, thus leads to  $(1-a_1)(1-a_2)(1-a_3) + b_1 + b_2 + b_3 \geq 1$, which essentially leads to a product of complements of the variables in $A$. Can this be expressed in terms of linear constraints?

Comment: Related to [Expressing a chain of boolean ORs using ILP](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/1300/145) and [Expressing a chain of boolean ORs using ILP involving different variables](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/1336/145).

Comment: Yes they are related, I had asked them, should I mention that in the question?

Comment: Instead of changing $\wedge$ to $\prod$, you can distribute the $\vee$ to get conjunctive normal form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For boolean formulas, you can use the following systematic approach. First, convert your formula to conjunctive normal form. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Converting_from_first-order_logic) details how to do this.

Applied to this specific case it follows that
$$(a_1 \vee a_2 \vee a_3) \Longrightarrow (b_1 \vee b_2 \vee b_3)$$
is equivalent to
$$(\bar{a}_1 \vee b_1 \vee b_2 \vee b_3) \wedge (\bar{a}_2 \vee b_1 \vee b_2 \vee b_3) \wedge (\bar{a}_3 \vee b_1 \vee b_2 \vee b_3).$$

We then add a constraint for each clause:
$$\begin{align}
1 - a_1 + b_1 + b_2 + b_3 & \ge 1\\
1 - a_2 + b_1 + b_2 + b_3 & \ge 1\\
1 - a_3 + b_1 + b_2 + b_3 & \ge 1,
\end{align}$$
or equivalently
$$\begin{align}
a_1 &\le b_1 + b_2 + b_3\\
a_2 &\le b_1 + b_2 + b_3\\
a_3 &\le b_1 + b_2 + b_3.
\end{align}$$

Note that this formulation is at least as strong as the one proposed by YukiJ, as adding the constraints together gives
$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 \le 3(b_1 + b_2 + b_3).$$

In general, different approaches may give different formulations, and I am not claiming that this is the best approach. For more information, you may consider the book [Logic and Integer Programming by H. Paul Williams](https://www.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-92280-5).

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your question correctly then you want to model that if $$a_1+a_2+a_3\geq 1$$ then it follows that $$b_1+b_2+b_3\geq 1.$$ Since $A \implies B$ is equivalent to $\neg A \lor B$ we want to model $$\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i < 1 \quad\bigvee\quad \sum_{i=1}^3 b_i \geq 1.$$
 We can replace $\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i < 1$ with $\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 a_i =0$ because the $a_i$ are binary and obtain $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 a_i = 0\quad\bigvee\quad\sum_{i=1}^3 b_i \geq 1.$$ This can be written as a single constraint in the following way:

$$3\sum_{i=1}^3 b_i \geq \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i $$

Now, if any of the $a_i$ is true then the constraint forces at least of of the $b_i$ to be true as well. On the other hand, if all the $a_i$ are $0$ anything can happen to the $b_i$.

Comment: Your final constraint is too strong.  For example, it prevents $a=(1,1,1)$ with $b=(1,0,0)$.  To correct this, you can change the right hand side to just $a_j$.

Comment: @RobPratt You are right, thank you! I introduced a factor of 3 in the constraint which should get rid of the problem.

Comment: Isn't $(a \implies b)=(\overline A  \lor B)$?

Comment: @ephemeral I accidentally switched from $A$ to $B$, I corrected it now. Sorry!